# Livewire upload files bigger than 10MB - Server Error Permission denied - smaller files no problem at all

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am trying to upload files to my local server with Livewire FileUploads, if I try to upload a file which is bigger than 10MB it tells me in the Livewire error message:

> "The abkfiles.0.abkfile failed to upload."

if I take a closer look into the DevTools I can see that the upload fails:

> "message: "fopen(C:\xxxxx\xxx\xxx\storage\app/public\livewire-tmp/bv8fQu1RmviPGqUcnCRW9MJQ8vbZ0y-metaY3AwMzkxMzIuZXhl-.): failed to open stream: Permission denied"

I changed php.ini max_upload_filesize and post_max_size = 2000M and published the the livewire config file and changed there:

```
 temporary_file_upload' => [
        'disk' => null,        // Example: 'local', 's3'              Default: 'default'
        'rules' => ['file', 'max:12282228'],
```

restarted nginx and cleared all caches and configs through artisan command.
But nothing worked for now.
What am I missing - it must be a Livewire Fileupload problem because I can upload and store files smaller than 10MB w/o any problem.
I need to upload files with up to 250MB to my local server - for documentations.

Any one here know what else I can try?

Comment: Thanks again Jason for editing my thread.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

- setup everything as posted
- restarted Server
- closed Chrome restarted and deleted cache ... now it works.
  I think it was an issue in Chrome.